# Find the number of clusters using clusGAP function in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

Could you help me find the ideal number of clusters using the `clusGap` function? There is a similar example in this link: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/factoextra/versions/1.0.7/topics/fviz_nbclust

But I would like to do it for my case. My code is below:

```
library(cluster)

df <- structure(
list(Propertie = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), Latitude = c(-24.779225, -24.789635, -24.763461, -24.794394, -24.747102,-24.781307,-24.761081,-24.761084),
Longitude = c(-49.934816, -49.922324, -49.911616, -49.906262, -49.890796,-49.8875254,-49.8875254,-49.922244),
waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 433, 456,825)),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

df<-scale(df)

hcluster = clusGap(df, FUN = hcut, K.max = 100, B = 50)
Clustering k = 1,2,..., K.max (= 100): .. Error in sil.obj[, 1:3] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you have specified `K.max` as 100, however, you only have eight observations in your dataset. As noted in the `clusGap` documentation, `K.max` is the
the maximum number of clusters to consider, hence, in your case, `K.max` cannot be greater than seven.

It is unclear to me that clustering is appropriate on a dataset of such small size. Nevertheless, please see below a working implementation. I have modified the `plot_clusgap` function from the R/Bioconductor [`phyloseq`](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/phyloseq.html) package to visualize the results.

```
library(data.table)
library(cluster)
library(factoextra) # for hcut function

df <- data.table(properties = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                latitude = c(-24.779225, -24.789635, -24.763461, -24.794394, -24.747102,-24.781307,-24.761081,-24.761084),
                longitude = c(-49.934816, -49.922324, -49.911616, -49.906262, -49.890796,-49.8875254,-49.8875254,-49.922244),
                waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 433, 456,825))

df <- scale(df)

# perform clustering, B = 500 is recommended
hcluster = clusGap(df, FUN = hcut, K.max = 7, B = 500)

# extract results
dat <- data.table(hcluster$Tab)
dat[, k := .I]

# visualize gap statistic
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(k, gap)) + geom_line() + geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = gap + SE.sim, ymin = gap - SE.sim), width = 0.25) +
  ggtitle("Clustering Results") +
  labs(x = "Number of Clusters", y = "Gap Statistic") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 16, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"))
```

Here is the resulting figure:

[image: Clustering results produced by above script.]

I should note that all the gap statistic values are negative. This indicates that the optimal number of clusters is k = 1 (i.e., no clustering).